# Best Library to use for my card game application

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-animation

I was wondering what library or libraries I should use for an android project I am working on.

Essentially I am creating a trading card game app, where players play various cards, some may cause some simple explosion effects, also the cards would move around the field depending on certain actions taken by players (eg card destroyed would be moved to the graveyard) again mostly only some damage animation effects, and probably no 3d models, but possibly some simple shader effects for special cards (foils and etc).

So based on these criteria, what would best suit my needs? Simplicity should be a factor since I am new to developing for android.

Comment: Stack Overflow uses a Q&A format.  If you have a specific question, ask it, and we'll do our best to answer.  As stated, your question isn't so much a question as a request for discussion.  BTW:  read up on OpenGL ES.

Comment: the question was what library would meet my needs?, sounds like a legitimate question to me considering I do not know much at all on developing games for android, with so many options it can be hard to make a smart choice, and recoding because I find there is a feature I needed but it wasnt present is a pain

Comment: Please take the time to familiarize yourself with the SO [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

almost any game engine will do the work.
you can check this link: http://www.learncomputer.com/top-5-free-android-game-engines/
personally, i strongly recommand libgdx.
libgdx is a great platform and it can convert your application to work with IOS, Java-desktop, android, HTML5 and more..

Comment: is straight opengl a possibility?

Comment: yes, it is.
Read about GLSurfaceView